# I have a list and a dictionary. I have to check and print those values who is present in both containers. I am trying below code:

Tags: list, dictionary, coding-style, python-3.6

```
dict = {1: {'host': 'vm224', 'vmImag': '182356_HFS', 'Img_type': 'User'},
    2: {'host': 'vm768', 'vmImag': '182356_HFS', 'Img_type': 'User'}
   3: {'host': 'vm333', 'vmImag': '182356_HFS', 'Img_type': 'User'}}   
list1 =['vm224', 'vm768'] 
for i in list1:
   for key in dict.keys():
      if dict[key]['host'] in list1:
      print(hosts
```

expected output: should be 'vm224', 'vm768'. since these 2 hosts are matching from list1 and dict.

I wanted to confirm if am writing it right.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input (list1, dict) and expected output?

Comment: *"I wanted to confirm if am writing it right."* You can simply run the code to see if it works properly. If it does, then you are writing it properly. If it doesn't, then you are not writing it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify your code, first create `set` with all available hosts from dictionary. Then filter the `list1` with this set:

```py
dct = {
    1: {"host": "vm224", "vmImag": "182356_HFS", "Img_type": "User"},
    2: {"host": "vm768", "vmImag": "182356_HFS", "Img_type": "User"},
    3: {"host": "vm333", "vmImag": "182356_HFS", "Img_type": "User"},
}

list1 = ["vm224", "vm768"]

all_hosts = {d["host"] for d in dct.values()}

filtered_list = [v for v in list1 if v in all_hosts]
print(filtered_list)
```

Prints:

```
['vm224', 'vm768']
```